# messed up systemwide mime data base

Tags: debian, mime-types

In debian stretch (mate desktop) i messed up systemwide my mime data base. How can I restore it.

Note I renamed first my  /usr/share/mime/mimeinfo.cache. but the Problem is, I think it is broken.

```
    alex@Taomon:~$ strings /usr/share/mime/mimeinfo.cache.broken | tail -n30
[INFORMATION]
\documentclass
\chapter\sectionbegin 
# xmcd
ftyp3ge
ftyp3gg
ftyp3gp
ftyp3gs
ftyp3g2
OggSfishead
CMML
ftypisomftypmp42ftypMSNVftypM4V ftypf4v G?
OggSmdatmdatmoovftypqt
#EXTM4U
webm
RIFFAVF0AVI AVI NSVfMOVIz
<ar>!<arch>
RIFF
ELFMZ
FORM
=pod
=head1 NAME
=head1 DESCRIPTION
<?xml
<!--.sndMTM
MMD0MMD1if
MAS_UTrack_V00
TEXtREAd/*
#include#import
From 
alex@Taomon:~$
```

this looks not right for me. after running

```
   root@Taomon:~# update-mime-database -V /usr/share/mime/
Updating MIME database in /usr/share/mime...

Wrote 1109 strings at 2c - 6374

Wrote aliases at 6374 - 6ba0

Wrote parents at 6ba0 - 846c

Wrote literal globs at 846c - 8554

Wrote suffix globs at 8554 - 12edc

Wrote full globs at 12edc - 12f1c

Wrote magic at 12f1c - 1f5d4

Wrote namespace list at 1f5d4 - 1f710

Wrote icons list at 1f710 - 1f754

Wrote generic icons list at 1f754 - 20330

Wrote types list at 20330 - 20f98
```

The new cache is empty.

```
alex@Taomon:~$ strings /usr/share/mime/mimeinfo.cache
[MIME Cache]
alex@Taomon:~$
```

How can I solve it.

I also can not use xdg-mime for setting default applications. Now filemanager is not starting without error messeages from terminal.

Thanks for reading with regards.

edit [paste strings /usr/share/mime/mime.cache](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zRggPZnCSc/)
edit2  [update-desktop-database -v](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/d9zVJ48Nxn/)

Comment: Thanks could resolve it by reinstalling every program that is from command `dpkg -S /usr/share/mime/` returns.

Comment: What does `/usr/share/mime/mime.cache` look like? (Not `mimeinfo.cache`, `mime.cache`.)

Comment: @StephenKitt  I edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update-mime-database` updates `mime.cache`, not `mimeinfo.cache`. To fix the latter, you need to run `update-desktop-database`:

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

Alternatively, you can reconfigure `desktop-file-utils` (which will do the same thing):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure desktop-file-utils
```

Comment: thanks for clearing my mind; but I get an error message, I add it to my question

Comment: That’s innocuous, your `mimeinfo.cache` should still be updated.

Comment: you saved my life